# Laziness and functional programming in CoffeeScript

Tags: functional-programming, coffeescript

Is coffee script lazily evaluated? If so, can I program coffeescript in a functional way?

Comment: Would the language home page be a better place to look for this information? Or maybe google?

Comment: Show me a google search that answers this question directly.

Comment: If you knew what lazy evaluation is, you could write a simple test to check it.

Comment: if it's so simple than why not show this in an answer?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=lazy+evaluation+coffeescript

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz Did you look at the results? Because I now definitely know the answer, and I have never used coffeescript.

Comment: @Marcin Based on the Google results, what and where's your answer? I saw no authoritative or even reliable answer to the question looking at those results.

Comment: Are you implying that if a language isn't lazily evaluated, you can't program in a functional way in it?

Comment: @NullUserException The first link shows examples of the coffeescript input and javascript output. Assuming it's not just a lie, then that shows that coffeescript does not magically transform everything to lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. CoffeeScript is a thin syntactic wrapper around the JavaScript language. Although its syntax may be more friendly for functional programming than JavaScript's, it doesn't change the fact that JavaScript is not lazily evaluated.

Comment: i've seen conflicting answers to this. I saw somewhere (i think) that coffescript wraps all parameters up as functions (partial application / currying). Can you add anything else in regards to this?

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz Currying and partial application have nothing to do with lazy evaluation. Also it's not true that Coffescript curries functions. An n-ary Coffeescript function will compile to an n-ary Javascript function.